# Using Laravel Framework, what is the best way to compile assets (js & css) files

Tags: laravel, minify

Using the Laravel Framework (5.1), what is the best way to compile assets (JS & CSS) files? Currently I'm using "devfactory/minify" dependency.

I need to minify all assets compiled once when there is deployment w.r.t changes. When there are more than 1 server then there is errors and also faces page crash due to the reasons

When compile runs on one server it serve page data but when user hits again and if it servers from other server then browser can not get that file which is cached by browser. Because on the other server the files exist but the file name is change due to timestamp is added in file name at the time of creation.

When the timestamp is removed at the time of minification then new version of file is uploaded but there is a need to  clear history of browser on client end which is not possible.

I need to fix it by minifying assets files and not to add version of file

Comment: you should use https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/elixir

Comment: Is it possible with using same devfactory/minify

Comment: don't know about minify but i can see it's very outdated library you should use built in function